# What does $f \mathrm{d}y$ mean without the integral symbol?

Tags: real-analysis

I ask myself what $f \mathrm{d}y$ means when there is no integral in front of it. I know what $\mathrm{d}x$ means when we have it in the integral.

Or is that the shortcut version ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the language of differential forms?

Comment: is $f = f(x)$ ?

Comment: no, not really @SamSkywalker

Comment: f means in this case for us $$\int_R^{n}  e^{-2pii ixy}*f(x) dx$$

Comment: the n should be on the Top of R(real)

Comment: So what the real Question is what do i do with this dy in $$(\int_R^{n}  e^{-2pii ixy}*f(x) dx)dy$$

Comment: It normally is a differential form. Could you please provide some context? Differential forma come in all shapes and sizes...

Comment: Don't you mean $f\,dx$ ?

Comment: You really should edit your question and include the details you are mentioning in the comments. Per your last comment, you have something of the form $g(y)dy$ (note the $y$ variable inside the expression for the integral, which is an independent variable inside the integral). $\int_{R}^{n}e^{-2piiixy}*f(x)dx$ is itself a function of $y$.

Comment: For reasons unknown, the comment where you posted the integral didn't appear when I posted my previous comment. Any way, I am a bit unsure what to tell you. Don't you have a double integral?

Comment: so far it looks like you've studied mainly analysis. this is more of a geometry question. try looking up tu introduction to manifolds or lee introduction to smooth manifolds